# error in initCoreNLP , specially "annoators"

Tags: r, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-mining, stanford-nlp-server

I have used coreNLP package & stanford Parser thorugh rJAVA,NLP,openNLP,coreNLP package

Here is my code

```
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
parse_annotator <- Parse_Annotator()
initCoreNLP(mem = "8g", annotators = c("tokenize", "ssplit","pos","lemma"))
```

during yesterday, everything is work,

but today, It dosen't work suddenly. showing :

**Error in initCoreNLP(mem = "8g", annotators = c("tokenize", "ssplit",  : 
  unused argument (annotators = c("tokenize", "ssplit", "pos", "lemma"))**

In my code, first 3 lines are succesfully run, but last line makes error

I tried to check memory ( CPU i5 : ram : 8gb),  reinstall R &R studio.

also, same code in other computer, thie error has apeeared too. 
Is there some error in code? 
or some error in NLP server? 
I cannot solve this problem. 
how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

FAcing the same issue... According to the version (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coreNLP/coreNLP.pdf) there is no parameter annotators anymore. The syntax is

```
initCoreNLP(libLoc, type = c("english", "english_all", "english_fast",
"arabic", "chinese", "french", "german", "spanish"), parameterFile = NULL,
mem = "4g")
```

You would have to use the following command, which will work but initialize all annotators (including a lot that you will not use that will consume a lot of memory (like coref)).

```
initCoreNLP(mem = "8g")
```

To still use the old version, you have to deinstall coreNLP and install it again with devtools with explicitly mentioning to install version 0.4-1 (and not the current version 0.4-2). Afterwards, you can use the same commands as before:

```
library(devtools)
install_version("coreNLP", version = "0.4-1", repos = "http://cran.rproject.org")
initCoreNLP(mem="8g", annotators = c("tokenize", "ssplit","pos","lemma"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the annotators directly in the StanfordCoreNLP.properties file in the package. This worked for me.